# Using string_split to store data in multiple columns instead of just one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to save a data of string2 ='DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567' into multiple columns of the table but it only move it to 1st column. I am using string_split function to separate all 4 string parts separated by ";".
What should I do to move this data into a single row across 4 columns?
Please see the details and result image below:

```
use TEST
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max);
DECLARE @sep char(1);
set @string2 = 'DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567';
set @sep = ';'
DECLARE @myTableVariable TABLE (id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name varchar(max))

insert into @myTableVariable
(name)
SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string2, @sep);

print @string2;


insert into EMPLOYEE (dob1)
select name from @myTableVariable
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use conditional aggregation. Unfortunately `string_split` does not (currently) support an ordinal position, so ordering of rows is not guaranteed, although in practice it *probably* will be.

Comment: It may be easier to use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` to extract the relevant parts of the string. But it would probably be even better to process the string in the application code that's calling your database; SQL isn't particularly well suited for general-purpose string manipulation.

Comment: Where does that CSV string come from? It's a *lot* better to handle this before inserting it in the database. All bulk import commands and utilities can handle `;` as the field separator

Comment: Any chance the source can format the string as JSON?

Comment: Yes I would use JSON or XML, it can be done using `STRING_SPLIT`  but that wouldn't be my first preference TBH

Comment: `Mar 1199` 22 years after Y2K - learn the lessons, don't use 2 digit years EVER!

Answer (score 4):

To guarantee column ordering you can't rely on *string_split* so need a different user defined function. This one returns the same *value* column and also a *seq* column for row ordering:

```
create function dbo.SplitString(@string varchar(max), @Delimiter varchar(1))
returns table
as
   return(  
    select j.[value], 1 + Convert(tinyint,j.[key]) Seq 
      from OpenJson(Concat('["',replace(@string, @delimiter , '","'),'"]')) j
   );
```

You can then make use of it as follows to create the columns from the sample string and insert into the target table:

```
declare @string2 varchar(max)='DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567', @sep char(1)=';'

insert into Employee(Dob1, DobNum, Pass1, PassNum)
select 
    Max(case when Seq=1 then Value end) Dob1,
    Max(case when Seq=2 then Value end) DobNum,
    Max(case when Seq=3 then Value end) Pass1,
    Max(case when Seq=4 then Value end) PassNum
from dbo.SplitString(@string2, @sep);
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd0b4f0ea4eddb9c2e7168f7c27695d6)

Comment: SQL 2019 version of String Split _does_ in fact have an option to _guarantee row ordering_ to match the input, have a read on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#enable_ordinal requires compatibility level 130.

Comment: No @Chris it requires you to be in Azure.

Comment: There have been a few blog posts about the latest releases of SSMS where it has documentation for an *enable_ordinal* optional parameter which is supported in Azure but not (yet) SqlServer. I suspect it will be in 2022 and hopefully might turn up in a CU for 2019.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you guys, its been working for a while in 2019, I last updated my server on Nov 2020, works a treat.

Comment: I give up. I'm not changing my apps though, been a godsend the string split

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Show us! The code was written in 2021 so I'm sure we'd all love to know how you got it running in your 2017 instance that was updated in 2020!

Comment: seriously I don't maintain this server, was surprised to see it myself, I'm really sorry if this causes issues for anyone but if it's any consolation it works really well ;)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller using `string_split` on *SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU13) (KB5005679) - 15.0.4178.1 (X64)* with the 3rd parameter returns the following: `Msg 8144, Level 16, State 3 Procedure or function string_split has too many arguments specified.`

Comment: @ChrisSchaller which is also the case when you try it in any of the online Fiddles such as [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c236b5b637c5af3806106110b31edc6e)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller And now your answer claims it works in 2016! Did you try it there too, or do you think version and compatibility level are the same? (Hint: they're not.) Show some proof! Undoctored screenshots! I'm serious when I say that if you have this working successfully on 2016 or 2017 or 2019 there are thousands of people who will want to know how you did it, because it is not working for _anyone else_.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server built-in `PARSENAME()` function could be handy for the task.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max) = 'DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567';
DECLARE @sep char(1) = ';'
    , @dot CHAR(1) = '.';
DECLARE @employee TABLE (
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    Dob1 varchar(20), 
    DobNum VARCHAR(20),
    Pass1 VARCHAR(20),
    PassNum VARCHAR(20)
);

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT REPLACE(@string2, @sep, @dot) AS tokenList
)
INSERT INTO @employee (Dob1, DobNum, Pass1, PassNum)
SELECT PARSENAME(tokenList,4)
    , PARSENAME(tokenList,3)
    , PARSENAME(tokenList,2)
    , PARSENAME(tokenList,1)
FROM rs;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @employee;
```

**Output**

```
+----+------+----------+----------+-----------+
| id | Dob1 |  DobNum  |  Pass1   |  PassNum  |
+----+------+----------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | DOB  | Mar 1199 | passport | AW1234567 |
+----+------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do this a number of ways, it is generally frowned upon, but because you have specifically requested `STRING_SPLIT` then I offer you this mechanism to parse the components of the string:

```
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max);
DECLARE @sep char(1);
set @string2 = 'DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567';
set @sep = ';'

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (SELECT 1)) as RN, Value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string2, @sep, 1)
```

| RN | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | DOB |
| 2 | Mar 1199 |
| 3 | passport |
| 4 | AW1234567 |

> **NOTE:** This *hack* for the `ORDER BY` is generally advised against
>
> > [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string
>
> However you could use this are your own risk if you really needed to use `STRING_SPLIT`

You could now access these tokens via their ordinal:

```
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max);
DECLARE @sep char(1);
set @string2 = 'DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567';
set @sep = ';'

;WITH Split as (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select 1)) as RN, Value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string2, @sep)
)
SELECT s1.value as DOBKey, s2.value as DOBValue, s3.value as PassportKey, s4.value as PassportValue 
FROM Split as s1, Split as s2, Split as s3, Split as s4
WHERE s1.RN = 1 
  AND s2.RN = 2
  AND s3.RN = 3
  AND s4.RN = 4
```

Results in this:

| DOBKey | DOBValue | PassportKey | PassportValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DOB | Mar 1199 | passport | AW1234567 |

### SQL Azure Supports an [`enable_ordinal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#enable_ordinal) flag

As an update to SQL 2019 and expected to be released soon, there is an `enable_ordinal` argument that can be used to ensure the sequence of the string tokens and it will include the *ordinal* value in an output column named `ordinal`.

> **HOWEVER** as of *11/06/2021* `enable_ordinal` argument and `ordinal` output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only).

When available we can simplify the previous query:

```
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max);
DECLARE @sep char(1);
set @string2 = 'DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567';
set @sep = ';'

;WITH Split as (
    SELECT Ordinal, Value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string2, @sep, 1)
)
SELECT s1.Value as DOBKey, s2.Value as DOBValue, s3.Value as PassportKey, s4.Value as PassportValue 
FROM Split as s1, Split as s2, Split as s3, Split as s4
WHERE s1.Ordinal = 1 
  AND s2.Ordinal = 2
  AND s3.Ordinal = 3
  AND s4.Ordinal = 4
```

You can use the same CTE to extract the `DOBValue` and the `PassportValue` in the `INSERT`:

```
DECLARE @string2 varchar(max);
DECLARE @sep char(1);
set @string2 = 'DOB;Mar 1199;passport;AW1234567';
set @sep = ';'

;WITH Split as (
    SELECT Ordinal, Value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@string2, @sep, 1)
)
insert into EMPLOYEE (dob1, pass1)
select s2.Value, s4.Value 
FROM Split as s1, Split as s2, Split as s3, Split as s4
WHERE s1.Ordinal = 1 
  AND s2.Ordinal = 2
  AND s3.Ordinal = 3
  AND s4.Ordinal = 4
```

Should result in this:

| ID | dob1 | pass1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mar 1199 | AW1234567 |

Comment: As @Stu mentioned `string_split` does not (currently) support an ordinal position, so ordering of rows is not guaranteed.

Comment: There's no order guarantee without an `ORDER BY`. [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): `The output rows might be in any order. The order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string.`. An `ordinal` is only available in Azure SQL and hopefully the upcoming SQL Server 2022

Comment: Note that it is specifically documented that `STRING_SPLIT` does *not* guarantee the order the rows are returned in reflects that of the delimited string, and it does not return an ordinal position. As such, the above does not guarantee that the values will be put into the correct columns.

Comment: Thanks guys, we have a solution for that... give me a sec...

Comment: I really hope it [2022] does, @PanagiotisKanavos ; the community have been (for lack of better words) screaming for an ordinal column since the function was announced.

Comment: @Larnu unfortunately the SQL Server team has gotten too corporatey recently. Even SQL Server MVPs had no idea what would be announced at MS Ignite and the database is still in private preview. It would be strange if only Azure SQL offered `ordinal` but ... crickets

Comment: Working in SQL v14 (2019) Just make sure your compatibility level is set correctly. The docs say v15, but that is because they always show the latest and greatest. I tested on my on-prem db v:14.0.2037.2 (Windows Server 2019 Standard (10.0))

Comment: `enable_ordinal` does **not** work in SQL Server 2019. The [very doc you link to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#enable_ordinal) says `The enable_ordinal argument and ordinal output column are currently only supported in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only).`

Comment: Sorry, but [I don't believe you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb8PM.png) - not just because it doesn't work in a recent CU in 150 but also because 14.0.2037.2 was published a year ago (you are missing all of the cumulative updates that could have even been a vehicle for this change, even if they planned to back-port it to older versions, which I don't believe they do).

Comment: Interesting but mine is lower version, and it still works: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64)   Nov  2 2020 19:19:59   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: You must be connected to a different (Azure) server where it is working. It doesn't work in any version of db<>fiddle: [2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e215c647c3ddf1182400d644ecd8dfc), [2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4e215c647c3ddf1182400d644ecd8dfc), [2016](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=4e215c647c3ddf1182400d644ecd8dfc).

Comment: The screen shots and db<>fiddle links all intentionally demonstrate that I know what compatibility level means and that my compatibility level is high enough. Is it possible that you are _seeing the tooltip in IntelliSense in SSMS_ and presuming that since IntelliSense tells you so, it must work? Can you show a screenshot (no Photoshop!) of this actually working on your magical instance of 2017 that got engine updates nobody else did and that weren't even written yet at the time of your last update?

Comment: (Anyway, even in Azure SQL Database where your answer _does_ work, exploding the string just to perform three self-joins is about the least efficient way to do this. I'd much rather use `OPENJSON()` both for efficiency and because it actually works on versions that people are using and that aren't magic.)

Comment: How about I take out any reference to 2019 and paste in the MS note that this only works in Azure, maybe its time move over to Azure anyway, I'm up for it now more than ever.

Comment: I think it would be much more interesting for you to show us and explain how you got this working in 2017. This would be immensely useful compared to an answer that shows code most people here can't use. (If you fooled yourself into believing it works because IntelliSense was updated in SSMS too early, and you didn't actually _run_ the code, that's ok, you can tell us. That would be better closure than just insisting it works on your special 2017 instance but nobody else's.)

Comment: How my server is installed and maintained is outside of the scope of this post, I have heavily redacted my response to appease the masses, I'm as surprised as you, it just worked, I'm happy and now i've spun up an Azure SQL DB and it works there too, so that generally means its coming to a service pack near you very soon.

Comment: Well, they don't do service packs anymore, and new engine functionality is very rarely delivered to older versions via any kind of update mechanism (never mind a GDR path before the code was even written). So, I guess we'll just move on not believing you.